# Why does my script update only the last row?

Tags: perl, sybase

I want to update a table with flag, wherever flag is 0, update that row. But my script goes trough all rows, makes the update statement, but executes the update statemnt only on the last row. Does anyone see where did I go wrong?

IF it helps im bekomming this error until the last row:

DB-Library error:
        Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending
Operating-system error:
        Error 0

```
use Sybase::DBlib;

use Sys::Hostname;
use Getopt::Std;

## additionals
use ADDITIONALS;
my ($dsn, $database, $dbserver, $dbname, $user, $passwd, $rmdb_config ) = ('','','','','','','');
my ($table_name,$file_name) = ('','');
$dsn          = "dbi:Sybase";
$database     = join (' ~ ',$dsn, $dbserver, $dbname, $user, $passwd, $sda_config);
$dbhandle     = connect_me($database);

 my $ctl;

$ctl= "select Table_name = Table_name, Filename = Filename from table123 where Flag = '0'";


    $dbhandle->dbcmd($ctl);
    $dbhandle->dbsqlexec;


       while($dbhandle->dbresults != NO_MORE_RESULTS){

            while(%db_data = $dbhandle->dbnextrow(1)){


            my $update ="update table123 set Flag = '1' where Flag ='0' and Filename ='$db_data{Filename}' ";
             print $update."\n";

                $dbhandle->dbcmd($update);
                $dbhandle->dbsqlexec;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there great benefits in `Sybase::DBlib` over `DBI`?

Comment: `select Table_name = Table_name` looks like selecting boolean `true`.

Comment: Sybase::DBlib over DBI dont rly know, i have to use it because of the perl driver on my unix.

Comment: select Table_name = Table_name is fine, i use it because i make associative array.

Comment: Why not add a print clause in while block, to see how many update-sql is executed?

Comment: You can see it, its already implemented in code:  print $update."\n";, like i said every update statement is there, they just dont execute, until it comes to the last one, then it executes.

Comment: "Are there great benefits in `Sybase::DBlib` over `DBI`?" None at all. Still using DBlib is a massive red flag. Sybase replaced DBlib with CTlib back in the last century. And, for Perl work, DBD::Sybase is better than either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two connections. One for the select and one for the update. That's what the error message is telling you. You can't run your update because you still have results from the select waiting.

On the last row, all of the results have been read and your connection is free to run that final update.

But DBlib is two generations of technology out of date. Please do what you can to get your system updated to using DBI and DBD::Sybase.